# Check MySQL version of domain provider

Tags: mysql, subdomain

I have been provided access to a sub domain of an organization's website to upload some content. I want to check the version of MySQL they are using as I need to use MySQLi. How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just ask them?

Comment: Run a query: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

Comment: @MikeW : thank you very much for your prompt comment. If i could have asked them I definitely would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the hosting comes with no control panel or phpMyAdmin which would show the version, you could run this query;

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `phpinfo` function. Just create a PHP file with the following code:

```
phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

first login MySQL database in command prompt afterwards you type the below sentence
  MySQL>SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"

Answer (score 0):

Using a `command client` (mysql), the server version of the `MySQL` server to which you are connected is shown once you are connected. The server version information includes community or enterprise accordingly. Both the version and version_comment variables contain version information for the server to which you are connected. Use the `SHOW VARIABLES` statement to obtain the information you want,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"
```

You can also obtain server version information in the mysql client using the `SELECT VERSION()` statement. MySQL Workbench also shows the server version in the Server Status tab and other clients like SQLyog has Info tab.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html